# completeness definition

Tags: real-analysis

I couldn't find a confirmation on this:

A metric space $(X,d)$ is complete if every cauchy sequence converges right?  Is that an if and only if statement, so if I had a sequence $x_n$ converging to $x$ in a matric space, does that mean that $x_n$ is also Cauchy, or is it if $x_n$ is cauchy then it converges?
thanks

Comment: All convergent series are Cauchy.  If all Cauchy series are convergent then the metric space is by complete, by definition of that term.

Comment: Yes, but I have here that a sequence $x_n$ converges in $(X,d)$ where $(X,d)$ is complete, then he states that it is also cauchy because it converges, so is Cauchy If and only if Convergent in a complete metric space, or Cauchy => convergent in a complete metric space

Comment: Convergent $\Rightarrow$ Cauchy regardless. Cauchy $\Rightarrow$ Convergent is the definition of what *Complete* means. So $(X,d)$ is complete iff all Cauchy sequences are convergent. See also what Brian just wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is if and only if: if $\langle X,d\rangle$ is a complete metric space, and $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $X$, then $\sigma$ converges if and only if $\sigma$ is Cauchy.

One direction holds in every metric space: if $\sigma$ converges, then $\sigma$ is Cauchy. (You should try to prove this if you’ve not already done so. it’s not hard.) Completeness of the metric is then the statement that the other direction holds: every Cauchy sequence converges.

Comment: Alright, gotcha thank you.

Comment: @werwe: You’re welcome.